# Owl Carousel not working in IE11

Tags: carousel, internet-explorer-11, owl-carousel

I have Owl Carousel 1.3.3 in OpenCart 2.3.0.2 (by default), and I can't get it to work on IE11.

In Chrome I see 3 layer of divs: owl-wrapper-outer, owl-wrapper and owl-item, which are not there in IE.

What should I change in owl-carousel.js to get it to work?

Site is: logisarok.hu

Answer (score 0):

from my experience usually caused by merged js files , try to unmerge